# Hosting Wordpress website designed in Instant Wordpress on IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-hosting

I've been at this for hours now and this just isn't working. I'm doing server work at my school and this guy makes a wordpress website for a class. The teacher wants me to host it on our web server which is running IIS. I've configured it to run PHP and mysql, both of those are tested and working. I've installed wordpress and the admin page kind of works.

The biggest issue is that none of the general user front end is working and I have no idea why. The PHP successfully echos text to the browser, but none of the requires statements are working and there are no errors. Whenever I run it through the silly Instant Wordpress executable it works perfectly fine.

The professor is getting a little agitated with how long this is taking and I'm at a huge standstill. Any help would be wonderful! I'm not sure what kind of files/logs yall would need, so if it's needed just tell me and I'll post it!

EDIT:

Index.php

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    echo "Hello TV Land";
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

The above snippet creates a blank page with the sentence "Hello TV Land" on the page.
Index.php

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Completely Blank page when run on the server.

Whenever I run the Instant Wordpress dev environment the page loads fine:
[Screenshot of Page Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqDZz.jpg)

Comment: You have to get errors to output.  What shows on the screen? Anything? Blank screen? You say "the php successfully echos text to the browser" - is this within a php file, using an `echo` statement? PHP and IIS (IMHO) are like peanut butter and dirt.

Comment: I completely agree, this has been a very unpleasant experience, however it's what the sys admin wanted... I'll get pictures

Answer (score 0):

If you open your wp-config.php file make sure that wp_debug is set to true and is not commented out:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

This will do two things, one is dumping a bunch of errors out onto any page and another is that it creates an error log file in wp-content/.log/ called wp_debut_log which should hopefully produce some errors for you.

If that does not produce any more errors, try opening your php.ini file and ensuring that PHP Error logging is set to report all errors:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

You'll likely get a lot of warnings and errors with error_reporting at -1, but if you're at wits end it can help.